# Spray.io: Can't compile test spec

Tags: scala, testing, akka, spray

I have the following service:

```
trait PingService extends MyHttpService {

val pingRoutes =
    path("ping") {
      get {
        complete("message" -> "pong")
      }
    }
}
```

`MyHttpService`is a custom class that extends `HttpService`and only contains utility methods.

This is the test spec:

```
import akka.actor.ActorRefFactory
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats}
import org.scalatest.{FreeSpec, Matchers}
import spray.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest

class PingServiceSpec extends FreeSpec with PingService with ScalatestRouteTest with Matchers {

override implicit def actorRefFactory: ActorRefFactory = system

override implicit def json4sFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats

  "Ping service" - {
    "when calling GET /ping" - {
      "should return 'pong'" in {
        Get("/ping") ~> pingRoutes ~> check {
          status should equal(200)
          entity.asString should contain("pong")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to run the tests, I get the following error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter ta: PingServiceSpec.this.TildeArrow[spray.routing.RequestContext,Unit]

 Get("/ping") ~> userRoutes ~> check {
              ^
```

Am I doing something stupid? Any kind of help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**: Although this might look like a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775106/basic-spray-testkit-usage-to-test-a-route-does-not-work), it's not.

The solution provided in that post it's not working.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `ScalatestRouteTest` already provides an implicit `ActorSystem`. Remove the `implicit` modifier from your `actorRefFactory` method and the test should get executed.

Comment: The above error arises as a consequence from an implicit ambiguity, because you have two implicit `ActorRefFactory` in scope. The one from the [`ScalatestRouteTest`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/api/index.html#spray.testkit.RouteTest) the `PingServiceSpec` is based on and the one declared explicitly as `actorRefFactory`.

Comment: Thank you! But why exception mentions `could not find implicit value for parameter ta` (which is  `implicit ta: TildeArrow[A, B]`)  instead of actorRefFactory?

Comment: I think because the compiler currently doesn't tell us, see [SI-6127](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6127) for more info.